# I can select randomly from a list... but how do I use this as a variable for different commands? Python

Tags: python, list, random, printing

Lets say I have the following:

```
foo = ('animal', 'vegetable', 'mineral')
```

I want to be able to randomly select from the list THEN, depending on which one is selected, have a set of commands to follow.

For instance, if 'animal' was randomly selected, I want the message print('rawr I'm a tiger'), or if it was 'vegetable' print('Woof, I'm a carrot') or something.

I know to randomly select it is:

```
from random import choice
print choice(foo)
```

but I don't want the choice to be printed, I want it to be secret.

Comment: If you don't want it to print, don't print. Thats it. Use it anyway you want, there is no compulsion to print variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random
messages = {
    'animal': "rawr I'm a tiger",
    'vegetable': "Woof, I'm a carrot",
    'mineral': "Rumble, I'm a rock",
}
print messages[random.choice(messages.keys())]
```

If you wanted to branch off to some other sections in an app, something like this might suite better:

```
import random

def animal():
    print "rawr I'm a tiger"

def vegetable():
    print "Woof, I'm a carrot"

def mineral():
    print "Rumble, I'm a rock"

sections = {
    'animal': animal,
    'vegetable': vegetable,
    'mineral': mineral,
}

section = sections[random.choice(sections.keys())]
section()
```

Comment: Thank-you, but I am trying to make a 20 questions game so it would b e longer than one message? It would then display a menu etc, unless there was some way or importing random 'def's?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to print it, just assign it to a variable:

```
element = choice(foo)
```

To then pick the appropriate message, you might want a dictionary from the element type (animal/mineral/vegetable) to a list of random messages associated with that element type. Take the list from the dictionary, then pick a random element to print...

Comment: but then for some reason it comes up with and error if i follow it with 'if element = 'mineral':' etc?

Comment: @pythonnoobface: Please show the full code which is failing, and what the error is.

Comment: `=` is not comparison, it is assignment, perhaps you wanted the `==` operator that checks if two objects are equal?

Comment: import random
choice = input('Choose your option: ')
if choice = 'a':
    foo = ['animal', 'vegetable', 'mineral']
        from random import choice
        if choice(foo) = 'animal':
            animalmenu()
        if choice(foo) = 'vegetable':
            vegetablemenu()
        if choice(foo) = 'mineral':
            mineralmenu()

#this then links to menus depending but it says that the = in 'if choice = 'a':' I don't see how though...

Comment: @pythonnoobface: It will be a lot easier to read this if you edit it into the question, where you can format it properly. And as bradley.ayers mentions, try == instead of =

Answer (score 1):

You just assign your randomly selected item to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> messages = {"animal" : "Rawr I am a tiger", "vegtable" :"Woof, I'm a carrot", "mineral" : "I shine"}
>>> foo = ('animal', 'vegtable', 'mineral')                                     >>> messages[random.choice(foo)]"Woof, I'm a carrot"

>>> messages[random.choice(foo)]
"Woof, I'm a carrot"
```

or more condensed if you don't have to keep a tuple:

```
messages[random.choice(messages.keys())]
```